# How to install rabbitvcs on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)

Tags: software-installation, ppa

I would like to know if [rabbitvcs](http://rabbitvcs.org/) work in Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) using Unity and if the right repository for installation is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
```

Basically I need to have folder integration similar to TortoiseSVN on Win.

Notes: I am very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work with the PPA `ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa` anymore, but RabbitVCS is now available in the Ubuntu universe repositories:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

---

Run <kbd>Files</kbd> aka <kbd>Nautilus</kbd> and open your folder with your source repositories and you will see something like this

[image]

Comment: Great answer thanks, related article about Ubutu universe repositories http://www.howtogeek.com/194247/whats-the-difference-between-main-restricted-universe-and-multiverse-on-ubuntu/

Comment: just in case... how to uninstall the same package? thanks once again for your time.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove rabbitvcs-nautilus`