# Is it possible to integrate rabbitvcs with a file manager krusader Krusader?

Tags: 15.10, filemanager, svn

I am using Krusader as file manager and rabbitvcs, I would like to see notification for SVN (red/green icons) in Krusader.

How to achieve this?

If is not possible, could you suggest me another File Manager which could be integrated with rabbitvcs?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to install rabbitvcs on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701641/how-to-install-rabbitvcs-on-ubuntu-15-10-wily-werewolf/701662#701662?newreg=d19bda63ca7f49579b5075229190f5b3) for using Nautilus (i.e. the standard Files manager) for SVN notification and usage (just like in TortoiseSVN).
RabbitVCS is available in the Ubuntu universe repositories:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

After this and a reboot you will have file version status tags in the standard Ubuntu Files manager, and a RabbitVCS SVN context menu on your right mouse click.

So there is no option or plugin for Krusader I know of.

Comment: Please elaborate on the content of the link within your answer such that the question/answer are still useful if the link goes dead